# Use If condition in Karate to extract values

Tags: bdd, karate

I have the following JSON response -

```
    {
        "type": "StudentSchema",
        "version": 1,
        "students": [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "John",
                roll: "1234"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "David",
                roll: "4434"
            }
        ]
}
```

Then how can I extract the array in Karate with name John to do further validation?
e.g. I want to say if name == John then save the id

I am trying below but it does not seem to work -

```
* def userId =  get[0] response $[?(@students.name == 'John')].id
* match userId == 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say your JSON is

```
MyJson =  {
    "type": "StudentSchema",
    "version": 1,
    "students": [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "John",
            roll: "1234"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "David",
            roll: "4434"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now as you want to get the ID for the student whose name is john you can get it by using JSON path

```
* def JSONpath = '$..students[?(@.name=='John')].id'
* def userId = karate.jsonPath(MyJson,JSONpath)
```

It will give you an array of ID which satisfy the json path condition and you can do your assertion from that.

Comment: yeah and this also works `* def id = get[0] response.students[?(@.name=='John')].id`

Comment: Thanks a lot @PeterThomas

Suppose my json is nested 1 more level like below and i need to get "details" for key Maths  -

{
 "type": "StudentSchema",
 "version": 1,
 "students": [
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "John",
   "roll": "1234",
   "subjects": [
                {
                    "key": "Maths",
                    "code": "11",
     "details": "Mathematics"
                }
            ]
  }
 ]
}

Can i achieve this in a single expression ?